# Bash formatting text file into columns

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, text-files

I have a text file with data in it which is set up like a table, but separated with commas, eg:

**Name, Age, FavColor, Address**

**Bob, 18, blue, 1 Smith Street**

**Julie, 17, yellow, 4 John Street**

Firstly I have tried using a for loop, and placing each 'column' with all its values into a separate array.

**eg/ 'nameArray' would contain bob, julie.**

Here is the code from my actual script, there is 12 columns hence why c should not be greater than 12.

```
declare -A Array

for((c = 1; c <= 12; c++))
{
    for((i = 1; i <= $total_lines; i++))
    {
        record=$(cat $FILE | awk -F "," 'NR=='$i'{print $'$c';exit}'| tr -d ,)
        Array[$c,$i]=$record

    }
}
```

From here I then use the 'printf' function to format each array and print them as columns. The issue with this is that I have more than 3 arrays, in my actual code they're all in the same 'printf' line. Which I don't like and I know it is a silly way to do it.

```
for ((i = 1; i <= $total_lines; i++))
{
    printf "%0s %-10s %-10s...etc \n" "${Array[1,$i]}" "${Array[2,$i]}" "${Array[3,$i]}" ...etc
}
```

This does however give me the desired output, see image below:

[image]

I would like to figure out how to do this another way that doesn't require a massive print statement. Also the first time I call the for loop I get an error with 'awk'.

Any advice would be appreciated, I have looked through multiple threads and posts to try and find a suitable solution but haven't found something that would be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the `column` command like

`column -t -s','`

This is what I can get quickly. See the man page for details.

Comment: I can't believe I did all that for the same output haha. Only issue is I get column line too long.

Comment: Recalled this from long long ago, not sure about the details, maybe the manual might be able to help you.

Comment: Bugs: "Input lines are limited to LINE_MAX (2048) bytes in length." Could be the issue.

Comment: When I did this, it converted all of my UTF-8 characters into codepoints.